# Windows bulk renaming/replace the string

Tags: windows

I'm trying to rename the file from one format to other format.. 500+ files. Currently with notepad++ manually do it with individual file name. 
Is there any command or scripts is there, Please let me know, much appreciate all your help on this.

```
DB2.V12.RPT(DDG1RP01)   
DB2.V12.RPT(DDG1RP02)   
DB2.V12.RPT(DDG1RP03)   
DB2.V12.RPT(DDG1RP04)
```

want to rename into

```
ren DB2.V12.RPT(DDG1RP01)      DDG1RP01.txt
ren DB2.V12.RPT(DDG1RP02)      DDG1RP02.txt
ren DB2.V12.RPT(DDG1RP03)      DDG1RP03.txt
ren DB2.V12.RPT(DDG1RP04)      DDG1RP04.txt
```

that is, remove these "DB2.V12.RPT(" and ")' and rename into .txt file.

Comment: in NP++ it's a straightforward regular expression substitution to change your file list into to the list of `ren` commnds. Having done this, save as a `.cmd` file and call it from `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in powershell pretty easy. Copy this and save it as a .ps1 file. Change the paths to match what you have. Change the first line to match the directory your files are in and then the $location variable about halfway down to be the same thing. Note the first one does not have a trailing slash but the $location does.

```
#get all files in this directory
$files = Get-ChildItem("d:\tempfiles")

#Loop through each filename and rename it leaving only the value in parentheses and then adding .txt to the end
foreach ($file in $files)
{

 $filename = $file.ToString()
 #replace first half of filename up to first parenthese with nothing
 $replace1 = $filename.Replace("DB2.V12.RPT`(" , "")

 #replaces the last parenthese with .txt
 $replace2 = $replace1.ToString().Replace("`)" , ".txt")

 $location = "d:\tempfiles\"

 $oldFilename = $location + $filename
 $newFilename = $location + $replace2

 Write-Host($oldFilename)
 Write-Host($newFilename)

 Rename-Item -Path $oldFilename -NewName $newFilename 

}
```

This:
[image: Files Before]

Will turn into This:
[image: Files After]